# Why does placing a lock on an object of the main thread's instance work?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, synchronized, notify

I have a few questions on multithreading and waiting in Java on the following code.

```java
/*
 * Taken from
 * https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Java+Programming%3A+24+Hour+Trainer%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9781118951453
 */
public class TestThreads3LambdaWait {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        // Lambda expression for Market News
        Runnable mn = () -> {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    Thread.sleep (1000);  // sleep for 1 second
                    System.out.println( "The market is improving " + i);
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e ) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() 
                                                + e.toString());
            }  
        }; 

        Thread marketNews = new Thread(mn, "Market News");
        marketNews.start();
         
        // Lambda expression for Portfolio
        Runnable port = () -> {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    Thread.sleep (700);    // Sleep for 700 milliseconds 
                    System.out.println( "You have " +  (500 + i) +  
                                              " shares of IBM");
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e ) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() 
                                                + e.toString());
            }   
        };
         
        Thread portfolio = new Thread(port,"Portfolio data");
        portfolio.start();
         
        TestThreads3LambdaWait thisInstance = new TestThreads3LambdaWait();
         
        synchronized (thisInstance) {
            try {
                thisInstance.wait(15000);
                System.out.println("finished wait");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println( "The main method of TestThreads3Lambda is finished");
    }
}
```

1. Do `mn` and `port` call `notify()` when they finish executing?
2. Who is the monitor that gets notified? (Since `main()` is static, the code in `main()` is not tied to a specific object.)
3. Why does placing a lock on an object of the main thread's instance work (i.e., sending the notification to `thisInstance`, which is not tied to `main()` since `main()` is static). Is it because all `TestThreads3LambdaWait` objects are notified because `mn` and `port` are in a static method and thus tied to every instance?

Comment: Your questions don't make much sense. `mn` and `port` are `Runnable` instances. They don't do anything on their own. Which monitor are you referring to? Your `synchronized (thisInstance)` simply times out its 15000 ms. Nothing ever notifies it.

Comment: Sorry, I probably read the book wrong. So, does `wait()` function as a `sleep()` here?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No.
2. Irrelevant. Nothing is being notified in this code - nobody calls `notify(All)` anywhere inside it.
3. Because `Thread.sleep(15000)` would also do it, which is effectively what your `wait` call does, given that nobody notifies.

Comment: If `mn` and `port` called `notify()`, would (3) be correct?

Comment: it would then presumably not work, as your wait loop would exit after the first of the two threads gets to the notify() call, thus meaning that your main thread could continue even if one of the two isn't done yet. You want a countdown latch (from the j.u.c package).

Comment: Thanks. One last question: In this example, who does `thisInstance` hold the lock from? I'm used to seeing `synchronized` methods or blocks in Thread objects, where, upon reaching a synchronized part of the code, an instance (of the Thread object) would "block" other instances of the same object (from proceeding into that block).

Comment: `synchronized (x) {}` acquires the lock on whatever object `x` is referring to. The `synchronized` keyword can also be put on methods, but that's just syntax sugar for `synchronized(this)`, or for static methods, `synchronized (MyClass.class)`. That is usually a bad idea; locking behaviour is public API. You don't have public fields; you generally shouldn't have public locks. `synchronized(x)` will block other `synchronized(x)` statements. _THAT IS ALL IT DOES_.